# Make DIV filling remaining height

Tags: html, css

I have one DIV containing three DIVs. Each one has width set to 100%. The 1st one and the 3rd one have fixed height. How to make the middle one filling the remaining height?
Thank you!

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve]

Comment: Have a google for css flexbox - you can make the middle  one grow.